# Gitlab Runner Hangs on SSH

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd, runner

When I try to use SSH in GitLab runner that runs on Windows 10 machine and start pipeline the runner hangs on SSH command. I think it waits password or something else. I have added host and target machine public keys to "Deploy Keys". I am able to connect target machine in PowerShell or CMD without any password but the runner can not do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to SSH to some server in your script. More details on the exact command that hangs would be helpful.

Apart from password SSH could be missing the host key so it waits for user input to accept it. If it is a single server try running

```
 ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

**once** in a job. This will update your `known_hosts` file. If you run on Windows that should be persistent.

If the server keeps changing you might have to run the command on every build. This comes with some severe security drawbacks and makes your CI vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: I have created SSH key with 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' for a user that is in my company domain. Does runner need administrator ssh key or something else? I do not know.  Also i have searched C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh directory but there is no .ssh directory for Administrator user. Currently i use 'ytg' user and my ssh keys are in C:\Users\ytg\.ssh directory.

Comment: Note that the issue I described is not about your SSH **key**, but about the SSH **fingerprint** of the server you are trying to contact. 
GitLab runner will generally run with some user, might be yours, might be some other depending on the setup or policy in your company. The SSH **key** to connect to the server should not be password protected otherwise SSH may ask for a password there, too (look at the `-N` option of ssh-keygen).
Also note that anyone who has access to your project will be able to use the private key. This may be a security issue.

Comment: I have tried to generate ssh key & authorized_keys file in yml file and i have seen the ssh key & authorized_keys are generated with user "Authenticated Users". I have copies generated public key into target machine "authorized_keys" file and copied target machine public key into generated authorized_keys file.  Also i have copied known_hosts file that is used by administrator user. However, the runner hangs on scp command again. What am i missing?

Comment: It is really hard to diagnose. Maybe add a `-v` flag to your command to generate some output. That should help to get an idea where exactly it hangs.